# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

Hi I am using Spring MVC. In my controller I am expecting form data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/data/grid", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getData(@RequestBody DataGrid dataGrid) {   }
```

But I'm getting this `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported`  error. I am curious it could be because of HsshMap in my formbean object `DataGrid`  This is how the this object looks like:

```
public class DataGrid implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5979434283059930104L;
private String                  transactionAction;
private String                  transactionDate;
private List<GridColumn> columns;
private List<Map<GridColumnName,Object>> rows;


public Grid(){
    this.columns = new ArrayList<GridColumn>();
    this.rows = new ArrayList<Map<GridColumnName,Object>>();

}

    ...getter setter here
```

Comment: Do you have Jackson on your classpath? MappingJackson(2)HttpMessageConverter might not be registered due to that fact.

Comment: and if you have Jackson, which version?

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly same issue except I was returning `ResponseEntity<T>`. I tried lot of solutions but none of them worked. Added Jackson ASL dependency and `<mvc:annotationDriven />` also but nothing solved my problem (Though `<mvc:annotationDriven />` was mandatory). Then found below link:

> https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Adding below dependency in pom.xml resolved my issue which was AWESOME !!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

While calling the Java method write below code in JS:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```